Slack Custom Fields Not Updating Through API
Having an Issue that custom properties doesn't update via API
saw a similar question on slack forum - link
Also tried following this SO answer  - link
The Issue on their question was field didn't allow API edit - mines does

My code looks like so
current_ts = str(int(time.time())) 
res = app.client.users_profile_set(user=user_id, profile={
"fields": {ai_p_field_id: {"value": current_ts}
}})


The returned res shows the "old" value and not current_ts
What am I doing wrong ?
